# Provide program arguments when debugging with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I cant seem to work out how to add program arguments to the launch command for the codeblocks debugger. Any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found it. Project --> Set programs arguments (i was looking all over project settings like visual studio has it)