# Opening a file from command line arguments in C

Tags: c, fopen

I want my C program to ask the user to type the name of the file they want to open and print the contents of that file to the screen. I am working from the C tutorial and have the following code so far. But when I execute it, it doesn't actually allow me to enter the file name. (I get the 'press any button to continue', I am using codeblocks)

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    printf("Enter the file name: \n");
    //scanf
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            int x;
            /* Read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF, which
               indicates the end of the file. Note that the idiom of "assign
               to a variable, check the value" used below works because
               the assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned. */
            while  ( ( x = fgetc( file ) ) != EOF )
            {
                printf( "%c", x );
            }
            fclose( file );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. This is how to ask a question about homework. "I've come this far and have hit a roadblock" rather than "Write this program for me".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read user input from a prompt, you would use the `scanf()` function. To parse command line parameters, you would type them at the command line, as in:

```
myprogram myfilename
```

rather than just typing

```
myprogram
```

and expecting to be prompted. `myfilename` would be in the `argv` array when your program starts.

So, start by removing the `printf( "Enter the file name:" )` prompt. The filename would be in `argv[ 1 ]` assuming you entered it as the first parameter after `myprogram` on your command line.

Answer (score 5):

This will read from stdin the filename. Perhaps you only want to do this if the filename is not supplied as a part of the command line.

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{ 
    char filename[100];
    printf("Enter the file name: \n"); 
    scanf("%s", filename);

    ...
    FILE *file = fopen( filename, "r" );
```

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up command line arguments with user input.

When you use command line arguments, you execute the program and pass the arguments at the same time. For example:

```
ShowContents MyFile.txt
```

In contrast, when you read user input, you first execute the program, then provide the file name:

```
ShowContents
Enter the file name: MyFile.Ttxt
```

Your program already reads the first argument `argv[1]` and treats it as the name of the file to open. To have the program read user input, do something like this:

```
char str[50] = {0};
scanf("Enter file name:%s", str);
```

Then the file name will be in `str`, instead of `argv[1]`.

Comment: Ah! You were right, I was mixing them up. Cheers for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

It's because your IDE is not passing the filename argument to your program. Take a look at this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218014/provide-program-arguments-when-debugging-with-codeblocks).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char filename[50];
    printf("Enter the Filename : ");
    scanf("%s",&filename);
    char line[50];
    FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r");
   
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File opening Unsuccessful\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(line , 30 , fp) != NULL)
    {
        strrev(line);
        printf(line);
    }
   fclose(fp) ;

   return 0;
}
```