# Expected ‘FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’

Tags: c, file, header, char, argv

I have a code where i give an argv[1] that eventually will open a file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  read(argv[1]);
}
```

The thing is that the `.h`  has the following error, "error expected ‘FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}’ but argument is of type ‘char *’"

This is the .h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
  int id;
  int *link_ids;
  int links;
  }; 

struct node *nodes;
void read(FILE * openedfile);
```

The thing is that argv[1] is going to be the name of the FILE (txt). Void read is the one that will do everything with the file. Also i  i cant modify in any way main.c
Can someone help me with my error?

Comment: You misunderstood the concepts about how to read a file. If you want to get the file path from the command line's argument. [This can help.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449295/2031180)

Comment: No, my function read is the one that will do everything about the file, in fact is working. The thing is that argv[1] is going to be the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv[1]` is a char array, you are passing it to a function expecting a `FILE*` parameter.

If you just want to pass the name of the file as an argument of the function it should be:

```
void read(char * openedfile);
```

Comment: Thanks!! but i cant modify in any way main.c

Comment: @Cipher, I edited the question to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is done by `read()` except from the file pointer assignment you should do this:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");
        read(fp);
        //..
    }
```